# How to specify an ArgumentParser subclass as an argparse subparser?

Tags: python, argparse

The [argparse documentation for subcommands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) says to add a subparser by calling the `add_parser` method on the object returned by a call to `add_subparsers`.  The `add_parser` method "takes a command name and any `ArgumentParser` constructor arguments, and returns an `ArgumentParser` object that can be modified as usual."

Beyond creating a subclass that overrides the `add_parser` method, is there anyway that I can add a subparser that is itself a subclass of `ArgumentParser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source, `ArgumentParser` is a subclass of `_ActionsContainer` whoich inherits from `_SubParsersAction` whose `__init__` sets a [`_parser_class` attribute.](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/argparse.py#l1064) .  This attribute is then used [to build the new parser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/argparse.py#l1090).

in other words, something like:

```
class Foo(ArgumentParser): pass

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser._parser_class = Foo
subparser = parser.add_parser(...)
```

*should work* (although I haven't tested it).  You'd be relying on an implementation detail here ... but I don't think there's any official way to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think mgilson's answer is almost correct, but you can do it without relying on implementation details like this:

```
class Foo(ArgumentParser): pass

parser = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(parser_class=Foo)
subparser = subparsers.add_parser(...)
```